# How can I colorize an imported model?

Tags: import, graphics3d, color

How can I colorize an imported model from for example 3ds max?

I'm trying to find the way to colorize a 3D plot from an imported model with something like this:

```
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["GreenBrownTerrain"][z^2]]
```

But I don't know how.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Example model: `Import["ExampleData/747.3ds.gz"]` it returns a `Graphics3D`

Comment: Following ssch's suggestion, you can explore the data structure with `jet = Import["ExampleData/747.3ds.gz"];
{jet[[0]], jet[[1]]}`

Comment: It consists of a bunch of different `GraphicsComplex` objects: `Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], 
  Table[jet[[1, 2, i]] /. RGBColor[_] -> ColorData[1][i], {i, 1, 7}]}]` Kind of annoying structure to change color of.

Answer (score 3):

Here I color the 747 model via the [`VertexColors`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VertexColors.html) option to `GraphicsComplex`.

```
jet = Import["ExampleData/747.3ds.gz"];
(* Function to change color of GraphicsComplex *)
newcolor[gcomplex_, colfun_] := Module[{
   pts = First@gcomplex,
   data = gcomplex[[2]],
   vcol},
  (* Remove old RGBColor stuff in data part of the graphics complex *)
  data = DeleteCases[data, RGBColor[_]]; 
  (* Introduce vertex colors according to colfun *)
  vcol = colfun /@ pts;
  (* Return a new GraphicsComplex with VertexColors *)
  GraphicsComplex[pts, data, VertexColors -> vcol]
  ]
(* Find range of z values *)
{zmin, zmax} = {Min@#, Max@#} &@(Last /@ 
 Flatten[Cases[jet, GraphicsComplex[__], Infinity][[All, 1]], 1]);
(* Color function that maps {x,y,z} to color *)
cf = ColorData["GreenBrownTerrain"][Rescale[Last@#, {zmin, zmax}]^2] &
(* Change all GraphicsComplex objects *)
jet /. gc_GraphicsComplex :> newcolor[gc, cf]
```

[image: recolored jet]

There are some visible artefacts in the coloring, but at least it's something.

Comment if there's some part you'd like me to explain further.

Here's the before/after for `ExampleData[{"Geometry3D","Phobos"}]`

[image: rock in space]

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try....Ok, it's working. tank you very much.

Comment: If I want to do a generic function in function of x,y,z for color, what I must do?

Comment: @user5288 something like `cf[{x_,y_,z_}]:= ...` or change `vcol = colfun /@ pts;` to `vcol = colfun@@#& /@ pts;` and use `cf[x_,y_,z_]:=...`

Comment: I can't do the generic function, I was trying all the afternoon, but I can, my objetive is colorize a beam in function of the stress, and I need a function in x,y,z

Comment: @user5288 What have you tried and how does it fail?

Comment: I tried to modify like @ssch said, and I can't do it work

Comment: @user5288 how do you define your colorfunction?

Comment: @user5288 Try for example `cf = Function[{r}, Sin@First@(r/10)]`

Comment: Or `cf = Function[{r}, Sin@First@(r/10) Sin@(r[[2]]/10)]` for a spotted airliner

Comment: Nice. Did you know that you can do `ColorData[{"GreenBrownTerrain", {zmin, zmax}}]` instead of an explicit `Rescale`? Oh, but that wouldn't capture the `^2`.