# How to import data from Blender or 3DS max file?

Tags: import

I would like to ask how to import a file from Blender 3D application and make a isolines plot.
What I intend to do is to make a terrain model in Blender, and make a topographic map of it in Mathematica. So far, I managed to save .blend file as 3ds format and import it to Mathematica.

Is it possible to extract the data from it so I could make an isolines plot?

Regards

Comment: [Somewhat related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17308/how-can-i-colorize-an-imported-model)

Comment: @ssch: yes it looks like what I am looking for.